# SVN: How reliable are conflicts?

Tags: svn, merge

I have to do a merge from branch to trunk. The two have become structurally quite different, with over half a dozen tree conflicts, and maybe fifty or so textual conflicts. Understandably, I'm a bit nervous about this merge.

I was wondering what exactly is the criteria for generating conflicts. Let's say a function F was inefficient, so the developer in branch re-wrote it to have a helper function G, and the developer in trunk re-wrote it a different way. In this scenario, I understand that a conflict will be generated over the function F, which was re-written two different ways. But would a conflict be generated over the function G, which does not belong in the trunk version? Or would the function G actually be applied and escape any notice? I'm worried about this kind of scrambled code that might result from the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion can't protect you from semantic conflicts.  For that matter I don't know of a version control system that can.

In your specific example the answer depends.  It's possible that the G function may be included in the conflict.  But if the two are far enough apart in the file and nothing else changes nearby the G function, then it's entirely possible that the merge will still keep G.

There are of course many other ways to get semantic conflicts that will never be caught by a version control system.  For example say someone modifies function F to have a new parameter.  Another developer adds a new call of function F in a different file, which the developer changing F doesn't touch nor does he have the change in his working copy.  There's no conflict when the developer goes to commit the new function F even though semantically his change conflicts with the existing code in the repository.  With version control systems that we use today the solution to this is team communication, code review and testing.

The only way to avoid something like this would be if the tools doing the merge understand the language, not just the line oriented conflicts.  This of course means that your version control tool would need to support every language you use it with.  Which would make it far less useful as a general purpose tool.

There is however one implementation of a semantically aware merge tool.  [SemanticMerge](http://www.semanticmerge.com/) supports this for C# and Java.  Subversion supports external merge tools and I understand that some users have used this tool to handle these sorts of cases.

In practice these issues really don't come up all that often.